# @ActionLink() in resource file?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I would like to include
    @Html.ActionLink()
commands in my resource file, but can't get them display properly when I call on the resource. Basically a resource entry like this:

```
<div>Click here to @Html.ActionLink("contact us", null)</div>
```

displays as

```
Click here to @Html.ActionLink("contact us", null)
```

instead of

```
Click here to contact us
```

in my view. Is there any way to get the razor tags to be properly read?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you can embed actual code in the resource file, and expect the view engine to invoke that at render time, it probably thinks it's just a string (and it shouldn't have to think any more than that).

A better way would be to use `string.Format`.

Store the resource as:

```
<div>Click here to {0}</div>
```

And then in the View (i'm guessing your using Razor):

```
@string.Format(Resources.Global.LinkHtmlFormat, Html.ActionLink("contact us", null))
```

If your doing this a lot, you could also "sweeten it up" with a custom HTML helper:

```
public static MvcHtmlString ResourceBasedActionLink(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string resourceName, string linkText, string actionName, string controllerName, object htmlAttributes)
{
   var link = htmlhelper.ActionLink(linkText, actionName, controllerName, htmlAttributes);
   return MvcHtmlString.Create(string.Format(resourceName, link)));
}
```

And then:

```
@Html.ResourceBasedActionLink(Resources.Global.LinkHtmlFormat, "Contact Us", "Contact", Controller", null)
```

Comment: Excellent idea. And I could define tags for certain frequently used links and have them replaced automatically in the helper so I don' rely on passing parameters everytime I call the method. Thanks a lot!

Comment: ps. the @string.Format(...) should be encased in an @Html.Raw(...) to prevent character escaping (as per: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14707484/how-to-escape-html-actionlink-a-a-tags-in-string-format)