# How to escape html.actionLink <a></a> tags in string.format

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

To make an URL within a translatable text we use `{0}` as placeholder.

So we do:

```
@string.Format(@translationHelper.GetTranslation("label-ClickToContinue"),
    @Html.ActionLink(
        @translationHelper.GetTranslation("text-here"),
               "Login",
               new { Model.UserName, Model.UniqueId }
    )
)
```

Translation keys:

```
label-ClickToContinue = "Click {0} to continue"
text-here = "here"
```

But this prints the escaped string into the source: `&lt;a href="/Login/Login?UserName=alberttest3&amp;amp;UniqueId=f3647fed-bab4-4575-bb5f-98ed27edff43"&gt;label-RequestNewOfficeWizard&lt;/a&gt;`

How to make sure that it'll not show the html-tag, but the URL?

Comment: Have you tried @Html.Raw

Comment: Does it support placeholders like `{0}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It easy **just put the output from `string.Format()` inside a `Html.Raw()`** like this:

```
@Html.Raw(string.Format(@translationHelper.GetTranslation("label-ClickToContinue"),
       @Html.ActionLink(
            @translationHelper.GetTranslation("text-here"),
            "Login",
            new { Model.UserName, Model.UniqueId }
       )
))
```

Translation keys:

```
label-ClickToContinue = "Click {0} to continue"
text-here = "here"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported by the ActionLink helper. It always HTML encodes the text. You could either write your own custom helper that doesn't encode the text or simply:

```
<a href="@Url.Action(Login, new { UserName, Model.UniqueId })">
    @Html.Raw(translationHelper.GetTranslation("text-here"))
</a>
```

By the way now that I have posted this code it looks so ugly. Go ahead and write a custom helper:

```
public static class HtmlExtensions
{
    public static IHtmlString ActionLinkLocalized(
        this HtmlHelper html, 
        string translationText, 
        string actionName, 
        object routeValues
    )
    {
        var urlHelper = new UrlHelper(html.ViewContext.RequestContext);
        var anchor = new TagBuilder("a");
        anchor.Attributes["href"] = urlHelper.Action(actionName, routeValues);
        anchor.InnerHtml = TranslationHelper.GetTranslation(translationText);
        return new HtmlString(anchor.ToString());
    }
}
```

and in your view simply:

```
@Html.ActionLinkLocalized("text-here", "Login", new { UserName, Model.UniqueId })
```

Comment: Second is no-go for reasons. The first is not so useful because I want to be able to translate the ClickToContinue text which contains the placeholder `{0}`. No more options left? Isn't there some sort of Html.format()?

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake in my answer. You should use `@Html.Raw(translationHelper.GetTranslation("text-here"))` in the first case to avoid encoding the output. Also why writing helpers is a no-go? You prefer spaghettifying your views?

Comment: Well, I'm not in the position to make helpers like that, just now. I wonder why MS would modify my strings when using `String.format()`. But since it looks like impossible to do it in a predefined way, I'll make two strings of the `label-ClickToContinue` (it looks so ugly but there is no option)

Comment: Oh I didn't understood that you were trying to unescape the `label-ClickToContinue` text. Sorry. Hopefully the Html.Raw helper that I suggested is working for you.